# How to add space on selectInput list

Tags: r, shiny

I was trying to list using selectInput from a file as like this

```
data4<-read.delim("data/data4.txt",sep = ",",header = T)

selectInput("show_vars5", 'YYYYY', names(data4), multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE,selected = 'xxx')
```

But list is showing with dot instead of space. Example if I have "cat dog" in data4, the selectInput showing as like this "cat.dog"
How to change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have column names with spaces in them.

`read.delim` is automatically converting them by concatenating them with a dot.

Exchanging `names(data4)` with `gsub('\\.', ' ', names(data4))` should do the trick. This replaces every occurrence of a dot with a space in the names of `data4`.

edit:
As @Stéphane Laurent pointed out, using `read.delim` with `check.names = FALSE` as argument will prevent the conversion of the names in the first place.

Comment: Instead of using `gsub`, one can use the option `check.names = FALSE` in `read.delim`.